# what is the best way to convert a json formatted key value pair to ruby hash with symbol as key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am wondering what is the best way to convert a json formatted key value pair to ruby hash with symbol as key:
example:

```
{ 'user': { 'name': 'foo', 'age': 40, 'location': { 'city' : 'bar', 'state': 'ca' } } }
==> 
{ :user=>{ :name => 'foo', :age =>'40', :location=>{ :city => 'bar', :state=>'ca' } } }
```

Is there a helper method can do this?

Comment: try this `http://stackoverflow.com/a/43773159/1297435` for rails 4.1

Answer (score 279):

using the json gem when parsing the json string you can pass in the symbolize_names option. See here: http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html (look under parse)

eg:

```
>> s ="{\"akey\":\"one\",\"bkey\":\"two\"}"
>> JSON.parse(s,:symbolize_names => true)
=> {:akey=>"one", :bkey=>"two"}
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9 includes this library, by the way.

Comment: didnt this used to be `:symbolize_keys` ? why did that name change?

Comment: @Lukas: `symbolize_keys` is a Rails thing.

Comment: :symbolize_names is a Ruby  thing though

Answer (score 22):

Leventix, thank you for your answer.

The **Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h))** method probably has the most integrity of the various methods because it preserves the original key types *recursively*.

This is important in case you have a nested hash with a mix of string and symbol keys and you want to preserve that mix upon decode (for instance, this could happen if your hash contains your own custom objects in addition to highly complex/nested third-party objects whose keys you cannot manipulate/convert for whatever reason, like a project time constraint).

E.g.:

```
h = {
      :youtube => {
                    :search   => 'daffy',                 # nested symbol key
                    'history' => ['goofy', 'mickey']      # nested string key
                  }
    }
```

**Method 1**:  JSON.parse - symbolizes all keys recursively => Does not preserve original mix

```
JSON.parse( h.to_json, {:symbolize_names => true} )
  => { :youtube => { :search=> "daffy", :history => ["goofy", "mickey"] } }
```

**Method 2**:  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode - symbolizes top-level keys only => Does not preserve original mix

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode( ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h) ).symbolize_keys
  => { :youtube => { "search" => "daffy", "history" => ["goofy", "mickey"] } }
```

**Method 3**:  Marshal.load - preserves original string/symbol mix in the nested keys.  PERFECT!

```
Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(h) )
  => { :youtube => { :search => "daffy", "history" => ["goofy", "mickey"] } }
```

Unless there is a drawback that I'm unaware of, I'd think Method 3 is the way to go.

Cheers

Comment: There's no guarantee here that you have control of the other side, so I believe you have to stick to JSON formatting.  If you have full control of both sides, then Marshal is indeed a good format, but it's not suitable for general-purpose serialization.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't anything built in to do the trick, but it's not too hard to write the code to do it using the JSON gem. There is a `symbolize_keys` method built into Rails if you're using that, but that doesn't symbolize keys recursively like you need.

```
require 'json'

def json_to_sym_hash(json)
  json.gsub!('\'', '"')
  parsed = JSON.parse(json)
  symbolize_keys(parsed)
end

def symbolize_keys(hash)
  hash.inject({}){|new_hash, key_value|
    key, value = key_value
    value = symbolize_keys(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)
    new_hash[key.to_sym] = value
    new_hash
  }
end
```

As Leventix said, the JSON gem only handles double quoted strings (which is technically correct - JSON should be formatted with double quotes). This bit of code will clean that up before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 4):

Recursive method:

```
require 'json'

def JSON.parse(source, opts = {})
  r = JSON.parser.new(source, opts).parse
  r = keys_to_symbol(r) if opts[:symbolize_names]
  return r
end

def keys_to_symbol(h)
  new_hash = {}
  h.each do |k,v|
    if v.class == String || v.class == Fixnum || v.class == Float
      new_hash[k.to_sym] = v
    elsif v.class == Hash
      new_hash[k.to_sym] = keys_to_symbol(v)
    elsif v.class == Array
      new_hash[k.to_sym] = keys_to_symbol_array(v)
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Type not supported: #{v.class}"
    end
  end
  return new_hash
end

def keys_to_symbol_array(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |i|
    if i.class == Hash
      new_array << keys_to_symbol(i)
    elsif i.class == Array
      new_array << keys_to_symbol_array(i)
    else
      new_array << i
    end
  end
  return new_array
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is a [json gem](http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html), but that handles only double quotes.

Comment: As madlep says below - that's all you need if you know that the JSON will be valid (e.g. you're making it yourself!)

Comment: This doesn't work. `JSON.parse(JSON.generate([:a])) # => ["a"]`

Comment: That's because JSON can't represent symbols. You can use: `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump([:a]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to use YAML serialization/deserialization, which also preserves the format of the key:

```
YAML.load({test: {'test' => { ':test' => 5}}}.to_yaml) 
=> {:test=>{"test"=>{":test"=>5}}}
```

Benefit of this approach it seems like a format that is better suited for REST services...

Comment: Never let user input get into YAML.load: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2013/02/06/yaml-f7u12.html

Comment: @Rafe do you mean this security hole of 2013 is still not fixed today?

Comment: Symbols are GC'ed since Ruby 2.2. `YAML.load` is meant to serialize arbitrary objects (e.g. for cache). The proposed `YAML.safe_load` has been introduced a few months after that blog post, so it's a matter of using the right thing: https://github.com/ruby/psych/commit/2c644e184192975b261a81f486a04defa3172b3f

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is by using the nice_hash gem: https://github.com/MarioRuiz/nice_hash

```
require 'nice_hash'
my_str = "{ 'user': { 'name': 'foo', 'age': 40, 'location': { 'city' : 'bar', 'state': 'ca' } } }"

# on my_hash will have the json as a hash
my_hash = my_str.json

# or you can filter and get what you want
vals = my_str.json(:age, :city)

# even you can access the keys like this:
puts my_hash._user._location._city
puts my_hash.user.location.city
puts my_hash[:user][:location][:city]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you might need both string and symbol keys:

```rb
JSON.parse(json_string).with_indifferent_access
```