# How to serialize/deserialize ruby hashes/structs with objects as keys to json

Tags: json, ruby, hashmap

I would like to dump a nested datastructure in ruby to json (I am aware of the Marshal module but I need a standard format) and be able to load/parse the datastructure again. Catch: I use structs (or easier for the example: hashes) as keys of hashes. Example:

```
require 'json'
h = {{hello: 123} => 123}
JSON.parse(JSON.generate(h)) #=> {"{:hello=>123}"=>123}
```

So the problem is, that JSON.generate(h) serialises the key {:hello=>123} as a string and when I parse the result again, it remains a string.

How can I solve this and regain the original structure after generate/parse?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.generate(h)).transform_keys(&method(:eval))` or `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h))`

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732001/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-json-formatted-key-value-pair-to-ruby-hash-wit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON](https://json.org/) only allows strings as object keys. For this reason *to_s* is called for all keys.

You'll have the following options to solve your issue:

1. The best option is changing the data structure so it can properly be serialized to JSON.
2. You'll have to handle the stringified key yourself. An Hash produces a perfectly valid Ruby syntax when converted to a string that can be converted using [*Kernel#eval*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) like [Andrey Deineko suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333571/how-to-serialize-deserialize-ruby-hashes-structs-with-objects-as-keys-to-json#comment91614485_52333571).

   ```
   result = json.transform_keys { |key| eval(key) }
          # json.transform_keys(&method(:eval)) is the same as the above.
   ```

   The [*Hash#transform_keys*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) method is relatively new (available since Ruby 2.5.0) and might currently not be in you development environment. You can replace this with a simple [*Enumerable#map*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) if needed.

   ```
   result = json.map { |k, v| [eval(k), v] }.to_h
   ```

   **Note:** If the incoming JSON contains any user generated content I highly sugest you stay away from using *eval* since you might allow the user to execute code on your server.

Answer (score 2):

> I need a standard format

`YAML` is a standard format that would suffice here:

```
▶ h = {{hello: 123} => 123}
#⇒ {{:hello=>123}=>123}
▶ YAML.dump h
#⇒ "---\n? :hello: 123\n: 123\n"
▶ YAML.load _
#⇒ {{:hello=>123}=>123}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where did the `_` come from? I have not seen it used in this case before.

Comment: @BenKoshy in `pry`/`irb` REPL `_` is the special variable which is equal to the result of the previously evaluated command.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by mudasobwa, YAML is a good tool: allows you to store also custom class objects:

```
require 'yaml'

class MyCaptain
  attr_accessor :name, :ship
  def initialize(name, ship)
    @name = name
    @ship = ship
  end
end

kirk = MyCaptain.new('James T. Kirk', 'USS Enterprise NCC-1701')
picard = MyCaptain.new('Jean-Luc Picard', 'Enterprise NCC-1701D')

captains = [kirk, picard]

File.open("my_captains.yml","w") do |file|
   file.write captains.to_yaml
end 

p YAML.load_file('my_captains.yml')

#=> [#<MyCaptain:0x007f889d0973b0 @name="James T. Kirk", @ship="USS Enterprise NCC-1701">, #<MyCaptain:0x007f889d096b40 @name="Jean-Luc Picard", @ship="Enterprise NCC-1701D">]
```